# PostgreSQL Monthly Database growth

Tags: database, postgresql

I have table in which i am calculating daily database growth.

```
 time_stmp| datname| datsize
----------------------------+----
 2018-05-1  | test    | 35 MB   
 2018-05-2  | test    | 38 MB    
 2018-05-3  | test    | 49 MB
.    
.    
.    
.    
 2018-05-29  | test    | 57 MB    
 2018-05-31  | test    | 62 MB
```

Even, i am able to calculate the total growth at the end of the month using below query

```
select
    time_stmp,datname,pg_size_pretty(sum(datsize))
from
    testtable
where
    to_char(time_stmp, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = to_char(date_trunc('month', CURRENT_DATE) + interval '1 month - 1 day','YYYY-MM-DD')
group by 1,2;


     time_stmp| datname| datsize
----------------------------+----
 2018-05-31  | test    | 62 MB
```

But i am not able to find exact total growth in each month and generate a single table output like below

```
 time_stmp| datname| datsize
----------------------------+----
2018-01-1 | test | 35 MB
2018-02-1 | test | 50 MB
2018-03-1 | test | 75 MB
.    
.    
.
2018-12-1 | test | 300 MB
```

Thanks for your response..

Comment: Done..can you please suggest now.if you have any solution for this

Comment: Your sample data is not clear.  What are the `datsize` values in the final table?  Are they daily points of data for the last month?  Are they sums over the month?  Are they rolling sums?  Something else?  Please clarify your question.

Comment: I am able to find database size every month end, just i need collect data of month end with month name..

Comment: I think you just are missing logic to check that a date is the last day of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT
    time_stmp, datname, pg_size_pretty(datsize)
FROM
    testtable
WHERE
    to_char(time_stmp + interval '1 day', 'YYYY-MM-DD') =
    to_char(date_trunc('month', time_stmp) + interval '1 month', 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Here is a short demo which shows that the timestamp logic is correct, and that the ends of months are correctly identified:

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for response, but the database size is not coming correctly. as you can see in month of may database is 62MB but is according above query sum of complete month.                                                    
 "2018-05-01 00:00:00" "test" "461 MB"